# Long landscape table: How to repeat the caption across multiple pages

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, landscape

I have a four-page table in the landscape which displays correctly except the caption. I need to repeat the caption and header row on every page of the table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|p{8cm}|}
    \caption{Caption I need it to repeat at every page} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Col 0}&\textbf{Col 1 } & \textbf{Col 2 } & \textbf{Col 3} \\        
    1&BLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  \\ \hline
    2&BLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  \\ \hline
    \bottomrule
    \label{ch2:tab3}        
\end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work: load the `caption` package, and change the beginning of your table to:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|p{8cm}|}
\caption{Caption I need it to repeat at every page} \label{ch2:tab3}\\ \hline
\textbf{Col 0}&\textbf{Col 1 } & \textbf{Col 2 } & \textbf{Col 3} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename~\thetable Caption I need it to repeat at 
every page (continued)} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Col 0}&\textbf{Col 1 } & \textbf{Col 2 } & \textbf{Col 3} \\
\hline
\endhead
    1&BLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  \\ \hline
    2&BLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  & BLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLABLA BLA  \\ \hline
    \bottomrule       
\end{longtable}%
```

Comment: I copied this code but It gives this errorMisplaced \noalign. \captionof{table}

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault,  I've made a mistake. On the subsequent pages, you have to emulate a caption. Please check the modified code.